# How can I implement a DTO for my service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Currently I have to models. One User model to store the password, and a UserDTO where I hide the password field.

```
public class User
    {

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class UserDTO
    {

        [BsonId]
        [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And now in my service that connects to my mongoDB, I want to change the model to the DTO version.

**Service :**

```
public List<User> Get() => _users.Find(user => true).ToList();
```

How should I approach this? Or should I make the change on my controller?

**Controller :**

```
public ActionResult<List<User>> Get() => _userService.Get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for a mapping library. Personally, I use [automapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html). To use it, install the NuGet package and create a mapping profile class:

```
public class MyProfile : Profile
{
    public MyProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<User, UserDTO>();
    }
}
```

In the service, you can map the types like this:

```
internal class Service
{
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public Service(IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<UserDTO> GetUsers()
    {
        var users = _users.Find(user => true).ToList();
        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>(users);
    }
}
```

If you're not using dependency injection, check out the getting started page in the link above for how to register the mapping profile. Otherwise, if you happen to be using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, you can register Automapper like this:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection().AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

There are other overloads for the `AddAutoMapper` method. This one discovers all classes that inherit from `Profile` in the provided assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can return UserDTO from service as well as your controller.

Service:

```
public List<UserDTO> Get() => _users.Where(user => true).Select(x=> new UserDTO{
   UserName = x.UserName,
   ....
}).ToList();
```

Controller:

```
   public ActionResult<List<UserDTO>> Get() => _userService.Get();
```

And you can use AutoMapper for mapping instead of `Select` method.

As a last point I want to mention, you should return UserDTO from Controller but you don't have to return dto from the service. This is a architectural approach and you can map into the controller as well.